# I want to know the life cycle when initializing a variable in the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, list-initialization

```
    A(const atomic<bool>& cancel = atomic<bool>(true))
        : cancel_(cancel)
    {}
```

After the constructor "cancel_" is "true" or "false" or demangle? 
(cancel is demangle, Because life cycle of cancle is done.)

1. I want to know life-cycle of `atomic<bool>(true)`
2. Can it vary between compilers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(const atomic<bool>& cancel = atomic<bool>(true))
        : cancel_(cancel)
    {}

    void print() {
        cout << cancel_.load() << endl;
    }

    const atomic<bool>& getCancel() const {
        return cancel_;
    }

private:
    const atomic<bool>& cancel_;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

output : 1

Comment: The default init. steps in when `A::A()` is called without arguments. The constant reference to temporary should live at least until return from constructor. Hence, the initialization of `cancel_` is defined behavior. But why don't you just pass a bool as argument for initialization?

Comment: I feel like there is more to this question than you're letting on. After all, if it were `bool`, I highly doubt there would be a question as to `cancel_`'s state after initialization. So why do you feel that `atomic<bool>` is special?

Comment: Ehem. Just saw the member variable `const atomic<bool>& cancel_;`! That with initialization with a temporary is not a good idea. This will become dangling after construction with default.

Comment: @ Scheff 

 This will become dangling after construction with default. 
=> And then why output is "1"? I don't know.. T.T

Comment: Sorry, your comment didn't reach me. (Please, don't insert space after `@` when addressing somebody.) However, I guess the answer (and, may be, my little demo) were convincing. If that's the case, please, don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The member variable will be a dangling reference either at the end of the ctor or at the end of the full expression the ctor was created at; the standard lets the implementation pick.

Following a dangling reference is undefined behaviour (UB).  UB does not mean a crash; it means anything can happen.

Comment: Yepp. I made a small sample to illustrate life times of temporaries in const references: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff1d6d9f7164e2a8) (and was just about to write an answer when I saw your appearing). ;-)